# Search for authors on Google Scholar by their field of study and country

Tags: google-scholar

On Google Scholar, you can do an author search based on keywords. For example, if I find an author who has "Robotics" as a keyword, and I click on that keyword, it lists all the authors with that keyword, in order of the number of citations.

What I would like to do, is see that same list, but:

1) Only for authors in my country

And:

2) By combining it with another keyword, e.g. all the authors who have "Robotics" and "Machine Learning".

Is this kind of advanced author search possible?

Comment: As an aside, it's worth mentioning that Google Scholar Author search only lists authors who have signed up to google scholar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can search multiple keywords with something like this:

```
label:robotics + label:machine_learning
```

in the author search. Narrowing by country can be trickier. You can potentially narrow by the email address. For example, if their profile is verified with a UK email address it will end in `.ac.uk`. Thus you can search:

```
label:robotics + label:machine_learning + .ac.uk
```

and only get UK researchers. You'll probably get some false positives and negatives with this technique so it's not perfect but will help narrow the scope.

Here's a related question pertaining to narrowing country on Google Scholar:

[Google Scholar: how to exclude some countries from the search?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/59681/google-scholar-how-to-exclude-some-countries-from-the-search)

Comment: Any insight on scenarios when it may generate false positive?

Answer (score 0):

A complimentary answer to [CephBirk](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/73420/154711) if you want to do it programmatically via Python. Additionally, you can add functionality to save those results to CSV/Excel or to DB.

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/search-for-authors-on-google-scholar-by-their-field-of-study#main.py) to test out extraction part:

```
# Iterates over all pages and extracts profile results.

from parsel import Selector
import requests, json, re

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "view_op": "search_authors",  # author results
    "mauthors": f'label:robotics + .de + "University of Freiburg"',  # search query
    "hl": "en",  # language
    "astart": 0  # page number
    }

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.87 Safari/537.36",
    }

profile_results = []

profiles_is_present = True
while profiles_is_present:
    
    # make a request
    html = requests.get("https://scholar.google.com/citations", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
     
    # pass response to HTML/XML processing library
    selector = Selector(text=html.text)

    print(f"extracting authors at page #{params['astart']}.")
    
    # iterate over profile results from one page
    for profile in selector.css(".gsc_1usr"):
        name = profile.css(".gs_ai_name a::text").get()
        link = f'https://scholar.google.com{profile.css(".gs_ai_name a::attr(href)").get()}'
        affiliations = profile.css(".gs_ai_aff").xpath("normalize-space()").get()
        email = profile.css(".gs_ai_eml").xpath("normalize-space()").get()
        cited_by = profile.css(".gs_ai_cby *::text").get()
        interests = profile.css(".gs_ai_one_int::text").getall()
        
        # append extracted result to the list
        profile_results.append({
            "profile_name": name,
            "profile_link": link,
            "profile_affiliations": affiliations,
            "profile_email": email,
            "profile_city_by_count": cited_by,
            "profile_interests": interests
            })

    # check if next page token is present -> update next page token and increment 10 to get the next page
    if selector.css("button.gs_btnPR::attr(onclick)").get():
        # https://regex101.com/r/e0mq0C/1
        params["after_author"] = re.search(r"after_author\\x3d(.*)\\x26",
                                           selector.css("button.gs_btnPR::attr(onclick)").get()).group(1)  # -> XB0HAMS9__8J
        params["astart"] += 10
    else:
        profiles_is_present = False

print(json.dumps(profile_results, indent=2))
```

Part of the JSON output:

```
[
  {
    "profile_name": "Wolfram Burgard",
    "profile_link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=zj6FavAAAAAJ",
    "profile_affiliations": "Professor of Computer Science, University of Freiburg",
    "profile_email": "Verified email at informatik.uni-freiburg.de",
    "profile_city_by_count": "Cited by 94818",
    "profile_interests": [
      "Robotics",
      "Artificial Intelligence",
      "AI",
      "Machine Learning",
      "Computer Vision"
    ]
  }, ... other results
]
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve it using [Google Scholar Profile Results API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-profiles-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan which differs by providing a complete solution without the need to figure out how to extract the data and maintain it over time.

```
# Iterates over all pages and extracts profile results.

import os, json
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),  # SerpApi API key
    "engine": "google_scholar_profiles",  # profile results search engine
    "mauthors": f'label:robotics + .de + "University of Freiburg"'  # search query
    }
search = GoogleSearch(params) # where extraction happens on SerpApi backend 

profile_results_data = []

profiles_is_present = True
while profiles_is_present:
    profile_results = search.get_dict() # JSON -> Python dictionary

    for profile in profile_results["profiles"]:
        thumbnail = profile["thumbnail"]
        name = profile["name"]
        link = profile["link"]
        author_id = profile["author_id"]
        affiliations = profile["affiliations"]
        email = profile.get("email")
        cited_by = profile.get("cited_by")
        interests = profile.get("interests")

        profile_results_data.append({
            "thumbnail": thumbnail,
            "name": name,
            "link": link,
            "author_id": author_id,
            "email": email,
            "affiliations": affiliations,
            "cited_by": cited_by,
            "interests": interests
            })

        if "next" in profile_results.get("pagination", []):
            # splits URL in parts as a dict() and update search "params" variable to a new page that will be passed to GoogleSearch()
            search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(profile_results.get("pagination").get("next")).query)))
        else:
            profiles_is_present = False

print(json.dumps(profile_results_data, indent=2))
```

Part of the JSON output:

```
[
  {
    "thumbnail": "https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/citations?view_op=small_photo&user=zj6FavAAAAAJ&citpid=6",
    "name": "Wolfram Burgard",
    "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=zj6FavAAAAAJ",
    "author_id": "zj6FavAAAAAJ",
    "email": "Verified email at informatik.uni-freiburg.de",
    "affiliations": "Professor of Computer Science, University of Freiburg",
    "cited_by": 94818,
    "interests": [
      {
        "title": "Robotics",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Arobotics",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:robotics"
      },
      {
        "title": "Artificial Intelligence",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Aartificial_intelligence",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:artificial_intelligence"
      },
      {
        "title": "AI",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Aai",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:ai"
      },
      {
        "title": "Machine Learning",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Amachine_learning",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:machine_learning"
      },
      {
        "title": "Computer Vision",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Acomputer_vision",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:computer_vision"
      }
    ]
  }, ... other results
]
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.